# PHP MySql query shows current time instead of the time from tablet

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP query to display the time an order was inserted on the database but all I'm getting in return is the current time not what I have on the database table.

```
public function count_todayorder(){
      $today_date = date("m-d-Y");
      $query="SELECT * FROM set_order_detail WHERE order_placed_date LIKE '%$today_date%'";

      $con=Utility::DB_Connection();
      mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
      $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

      return $count;
}
```

To display the table I'm using this.

```
<div>
    <b>Ordered date:</b>
    <?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
    echo $today_date = date('g:i:s A - m-d-y '); 
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Without second argument date() uses current date.

Comment: you set variable `$today_date = date("m-d-Y");` and you output variable `echo $today_date = date('g:i:s A - m-d-y ');` there is no any dynamic part for output.

Comment: Nothing is displaying the time returned from the query. You're just returning `$count`, which is the number of rows.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The div is hard-coding today's date. If you want date from the db, you need to query it. However, the function you showed returns the count of the query, not the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try to change this date formate

Database date formate is yyyy-mm-dd. 
So you should change your current date formate like below:

```
$today_date = date("Y-m-d");
 $query='SELECT * FROM set_order_detail WHERE order_placed_date LIKE "%'.$today_date.'%"';
```

Comment: Even after I made that change the result seems to be the same.

Comment: Nope that with this echo $today_date = date('g:i:s A - m-d-y '); or echo $today_date = date('g:i:s A - Y-m-d '); will still display the local computer time.

Comment: Could something be missing code public function count_todayorder(){
    $today_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $query='SELECT * FROM set_order_detail WHERE order_placed_date LIKE "%'.$today_date.'%"';
 
          $con=Utility::DB_Connection();
          mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
          $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
          $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
         
           
            return $count;
              
        
 } code

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not actually using the date from the database, but rather you are just using the date function without setting the timestamp.

This is the `date()` functions syntax: `date(format,timestamp);`

So using your code, it would be:

```
date('g:i:s A - m-d-y ', $dateFromDB);
```

You just need to get the date from the database, and add it to the `date()` function where `$dateFromDB` is.

Comment: When I make those changes I get a weird date Order Date: 7:00:00 PM - 12-31-69 instead of what is on the table 28-01-2019 09:17

Comment: ok, try this: `date('d-m-Y H:i ', $dateFromDB);`, also, did you trying outputting the date you get from the database to make sure you are getting the right data?

Answer (score 0):

To tackle the problem you need to firstly understand that you have 2 different servers. One for the `PHP` and one for the database-in your case `MySQL`. Latter server will store records based on the `time_zone` stored variable. By default that should be set to `SYSTEM` -if you haven't tempered with the settings.

To check that perform the following query `SELECT @@time_zone;`. In case that it is something like `+00:00` it is equal to GMT. Alternatively try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone';`

Thus, for integrity purposes, you should always rely on what your `SQL server` provides. Lets amend the select statement to;

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM `set_order_detail` WHERE DATE( `order_placed_date` ) = DATE( NOW( ) )";
```

...and remove the `$today_date = date("m-d-Y");` part which, is not needed at all.

> I assume that `order_placed_date` is either `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` since you haven't placed a data-set example.

Given query will return the date format which by default is 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Casting this into `PHP` via `date` function will re-evaluate it based on the `PHP server` clock, which is a non-go. To get the proper format you need something like this

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT( `order_placed_date`, '%l:%i:%s %p - %c-%e-%y') AS `format` FROM `set_order_detail` WHERE DATE( `order_placed_date` ) = DATE( NOW( ) );
```

> Please check [MySQL DATE_FORMAT function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for more details.

To continue, your function -like [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) wrote in a comment- returns the number of rows matched and not the content fetched via the query. Therefore, the function should look something like that.

```
// somewhere in your class add this
public function todayOrders( )
{
    $query="SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT( `order_placed_date`, '%l:%i:%s %p - %c-%e-%y') AS `format` FROM `set_order_detail` WHERE DATE( `order_placed_date` ) = DATE( NOW( ) );";

    $con=Utility::DB_Connection();
    mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if( !is_resource( $result ) )
    {
        return [];
    }

    $rows   = [];

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row( $result ) )
    {
        $rows[ ] = $row['format'];
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

> **Note**: do not replace your previous method, just append this one, in case there are errors on this method. I am not able to test it atm.

To conclude and to produce the set of results fetched via the db in your template try the following.

```
<?php $rows = todayOrders( ); ?>
<?php foreach( $rows as $today_date ) : ?>
<div>
  <b>Ordered date:</b> <?php echo $today_date; ?>
</div>
```

Hope it helped.